# Need help setting up <rule> in urlrewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a mysite.com website (SpringBoot 2.0) where I use the localization of mysite.com?lang=en or mysite.com?lang=uk
How can I configure  in urlrewrite.xml org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter;
To get: from mysite.com?lang=en mysite.com default en language

```
mysite.com
mysite.com/test
mysite.com/save/wer
```

Other languages

```
from mysite.com?lang=uk
mysite.com/uk
mysite.com/uk/test
mysite.com/uk/save/wer

<rule>
   <from>^(.*(lang=(ru|uk)).*)$</from>
   <to type="redirect">/%{parameter:lang}</to>
 </rule>
<rule>
  <from>^(.*(lang=(uk)).*)$</from>
   <to type="redirect">/</to>
 </rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule to achieve what you are trying

```
<rule>
    <from>^(.+)lang=(..)(.+)$</from>
    <to type="redirect">$1/$2/$3</to>
</rule>
```

Explanation : Split the incoming URL into 3 parts

Part 1: Every thing before lang=

Part 2: 2 characters after lang=

Part 3: Every thing after the 2 characters

Forward the request by removing lang= and keeping everything else

Comment: Thank you so. But for other languages I use httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher and I can't to set type="redirect"

Comment: share the code so that i can have a look and answer

Comment: but your first question clearly says you are passing lang=uk int he query parameters

Comment: Hi, you're right.
I have links for the default language:

http://my.domen.com
http://my.domen.com/cockpit
http://my.domen.com/cockpit?param=1&param=2
http://my.domen.com/?param=1&param=2
http://my.domen.com/uk
http://my.domen.com/?lang=uk
http://my.domen.com/uk/?param=1&param=2
http://my.domen.com/uk/?param=1&param=2&lang=uk

Comment: should redirect to a new link

http://my.domen.com
http://my.domen.com/cockpit
http://my.domen.com/cockpit?param=1&param=2
http://my.domen.com/?param=1&param=2
http://my.domen.com
http://my.domen.com
http://my.domen.com/?param=1&param=2
http://my.domen.com/?param=1&param=2

Comment: For other languages I have links:

------- INPUT-------
http://my.domen.com/en
http://my.domen.com/en/cockpit
http://my.domen.com/en/cockpit?param=1&param=2
http://my.domen.com/en/?param=1&param=2
http://my.domen.com/?lang=en
http://my.domen.com/en/?param=1&param=2
http://my.domen.com/?param=1&param=2&lang=en

Comment: and I need to get the link in the browser:

http://my.domen.com/en
http://my.domen.com/en/cockpit
http://my.domen.com/en/cockpit?param=1&param=2
http://my.domen.com/en/?param=1&param=2
http://my.domen.com/en
http://my.domen.com/en/?param=1&param=2
http://my.domen.com/en/?param=1&param=2

Comment: its too confusing and unclear on your comments. Can you check once and I suggest to provide in a table format what is input and what is expected